# MySQL - Order by grouped elements

Tags: php, mysql, web

I have a fairly basic search function which allows users to search for companies on various fields, using various joins. Part of this involves company addresses, which is a one-to-many relationship. One of these addresses is marked as the company's headquarters. The query might look like this:

```
SELECT comanies.*,customers.*
FROM _customers
NATURAL JOIN companies
NATURAL JOIN company_addresses 
WHERE company_addresses.city_id = '5556614'
GROUP BY company_id
```

As you can see, every company must have an address in this city to be matched. However, I also want to order the companies with those who have this city as their headquarters first. At the moment, all the addresses are grouped into one row, so the headquarters column can't be used.

How can I use get those companies whose headquarters are in cit_id = 5556614 to show up first?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a left join instead of natural join. Ideally the results should be all the companies and customers whos company_address.city_id = '5556614'. So you shouldn't be getting any other data besides that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to add this `order by` clause:

```
order by max(company_addresses.IsHeadquarters = 'Y') desc;
```

Or whatever the logic is for identifying the headquarters.

I would recommend that you put the same expression (`max(company_addresses.IsHeadquarters = 'Y')`) in the `select` clause so you can identify the companies with the headquarters in the city.